# My Parent controller also runs with child - angular ui.router

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui.router

Here is the sample code :

```
$stateProvider
    .state('contacts', {
        url: '/contacts',
        templateUrl: './home/contacts.html',
        controller: 'contactController'
    })
    .state('contacts.list', {
        url: '/list',
        templateUrl: './home/list.html',
        controller: 'listController'

    })
    .state('contacts.list.accounts', {
        url: '/accounts',
        templateUrl: './home/account.html',
        controller: 'accountController'
    })
```

list.html have two ng-controller in the two divs.

so when i go to  $state.go('contacts.list.account')

then my contact.html controllers run if i have on page then my list two ng-controllers run and then my actual controller run .

I don't want contact and list controllers to run .

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're state is nested using the 'dot notation' as *stated* in the [ui-router documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views#dot-notation) (no pun intended).

Taken from the documentation:

> When the application is in a particular state—when a state is
>   "active"—all of its ancestor states are implicitly active as well.

In your instance, when the "contacts.list.accounts" state is active, the "contacts.list" state
is implicitly active as well, because it's the parent state to
"contacts.list.accounts". The same goes for the "contacts" state, which is also implicitly active because the "contacts.list" state is active.

**If you do not want the other states to be active too, make the state a parent by change your state to something like this:**

```
.state('accounts', {
    url: '/accounts',
    templateUrl: './home/account.html',
    controller: 'accountController'
});
```

And re-reference `$state.go('contacts.list.account')` to `$state.go('accounts')`

Comment: But i am using breadcrum . i need that , so i can't remove it and do $state.go('account') . Is there any other approach .  or anything .

Comment: @Aman Unfortunately your application must not be architected correctly. If your `accounts` state is a child of the other states then the you should expect those other states to also be active. This is how `ui-router` is intended to work.

Comment: Ya it is working the way u told but for some reasons i dont want my other controller to run ..